# Tailwind CSS @layer directive does not work

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to set base styles for my project but *@layer* directive does not seem to work.

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "tailwind-base-layer",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.36",
    "book-atlas-widgets": "file:../widgets",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx webpack serve --open",
    "build": "npx webpack build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "postcss-import": "^14.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "webpack": "^5.72.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  }
}
```

My `postcss.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

My `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

When I add this to my css as shown in the *Tailwind CSS* documentation, the base styles won't change, even though other *Tailwind CSS* features work fine:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  h1 {
    @apply text-2xl;
  }
  h2 {
    @apply text-xl;
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

Also, maybe worth noting, that it's a React project and using webpack as a bundler.